# High load-avg on Heroku Postgres

Tags: postgresql, heroku

Some two weeks ago, I deployed some changes to my app (Flask + SQLAlchemy on top of Postgres) to Heroku. The response time of my dynos went up soon afterwards and the time outs in responses started. Before these problems started, the current app's version has been running flawlessly for some 2-3 months.

Naturally, I suspected my changes in the app and went through them, but there were none relevant to this (changes in the front end, replaced plain text emails with HTML ones, minor changes in the static data that the app is using).

I have a copy of the app for testing purposes, so I cloned the latest backup of the production DB and started investigating (the clone was some 45GiB, compared to 56GiB of the original, but this seems to be a normal consequence of "bloating").

It turns out that even the trivial requests take ridiculous amount of time on production, while they work on the testing one as they should. For example, `select * from A where some_id in (three, int, values)` takes under 0.5 sec on testing, and some 12-15 sec on prod (`A` has 3M records and `some_id` is a foreign key to a much smaller table). Even `select count(*) from A` will take the same amount of time, so it's not indexing or anything like that.

This is not tied to a specific query or even a table, thus removing my doubts of my code as most of it was unchanged for months and worked fine until these problems started.

Looking further into this, I found that the logs contain load averages for the DB server, and my production one is showing `load-avg` 22 (I searched for `postgres load-avg` in Papertrail), and it seems to be almost constant (slowly rising over prolonged periods of time).

I upgraded the production DB from Postgres 9.6 / Standard 2 plan (although, my connections number was around 105/400 and the cache hit rate was 100%) to Postgres 10 / Standard 3 plan, but this didn't make a slightest improvement. This upgrade also meant some 30-60min of downtime. Soon after bringing the app back up, the DB server's load was high (sadly, I didn't check during the downtime). Also, the DB server's load doesn't seem to have spikes that would reflect the app's usage (the app is mostly used in the USA and EU, and the usual app's load reflects that).

At this point, I am without ideas (apart from contacting Heroku's support, which a colleague of mine will do) and would appreciate any suggestions what to look or try next.

Comment: Running in exactly the same issue right now... 3 Months absolutely ok and now perf is a disaster

Comment: Not that this explains the load increase, but standard-2 and standard-3 appear to have the same available CPU. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-production-tier-technical-characterization#performance-characteristics The upgrade to standard-3 improved everything but CPU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up upgrading from `standard-2` to `standard-7` and my DB's load dropped to around 0.3-0.4. I don't have an explanation of why it started so suddenly.